# R dataframe column replace only first space before a comma with underscore

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, gsub

Similarly worded questions, but not quite what I'm looking for and am a bit stuck. I have a column of "City, State " values. Some cities have 2 words, like "Grand Rapids, MI". I would like to replace that first space so it becomes Grand_Rapids, MI. I'm using `separate` to create City and State values so I would like to keep the space between City and State. How can I do so?

```
Col1
Fort Myers, FL
Grand Rapids, MI
```

becomes

```
Col1
Fort_Myers, FL
Grand_Rapids, MI
```

So that I can use

```
df1 <- df%>%separate(Col1,c("City","State"))
```

to get

```
City         State
Fort_Myers     FL
Grand_Rapids   MI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `sep` here or else it could match other delimiters i.e. the space between the 'Fort' and 'Myers' as well (or if it is `_`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate(Col1,c("City","State"), sep=",\\s*")
```

Comment: great, that is a lot simpler than the rabbit hole I was down..thank you!